# postgresql nextval question on sequences

Tags: php, postgresql, sequence, nextval

I am trying to work with postgresql 'nextval' in PHP. How can I fill in the parenthesis in the third line in order to replace TXN_ID with the value of nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq')?

```
$DB->query("SELECT nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq')");
$DB->query('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED');
$DB->query('SELECT schemadb.undo_transaction(TXN_ID)');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell us what is `$DB` variable. I guess you are using PDO.

The question "Is there anyway to store the result of query into php variable" is kind of beginner question, and is easilly answered in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You must understand, that (from PHP's point of view) there is no difference between

```
SELECT nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq')
```

and

```
SELECT xcolumn FROM xtable LIMIT 1
```

If you want to fetch data values from ANY query, you do it always the same, standard way:

1. query
2. execute
3. fetch

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$DB->query("SELECT nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq')");
$DB->query('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED');
$DB->query("SELECT schemadb.undo_transaction( currval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq') )");
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. Is there anyway to store the result of "$DB->query("SELECT nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq')");" into a PHP variable?

Comment: Let's take a step back. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to get the ID of the next value of the sequence?

Comment: I want to get the ID of the currval in the sequence. What you posted before didn't work, so I'm trying to see if I can store the currval of the sequence in a php variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the interaction with SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED, but have you tried doing this:

```
SELECT schemadb.undo_transaction(nextval('schemadb.audit_txn_seq'))
```

The question is now what does "undo_transaction" return?  If it returns the transaction ID upon successful completion, then you're good to go!